# how can i add a package to flutter?

Tags: flutter

you know all packs are difference from each other how can i do that ?
how can i add a package to flutter?
this is thing that i want to add:

```html
Alert(
          context: context,
          title: '\پایان!',
          desc: 'You\'ve reached the end of the quiz.',
        ).show();
```

Comment: With "package" you mean an alert dialog? What you are asking it's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amin!

To install a new package to your app you need to update your pubspec.yaml file

add [rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) under "dependencies:"

Example

```
dependencies:
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
```

then save the file it should update automatically but if it does not happen run `'flutter pub get'`

Finally import it

```
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
```

Ps. to find new packages check https://pub.dev/ there great instructions on how to install package, Also if you are new to flutter I recommend you to get free course which is recommended by Google and now offer for free within next month, just google 'flutter course free'